# getting message Incorrect syntax near ')' in the last line

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, derived-table

I am getting this message in SQL Server 2019:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I am getting the error in the last line.

What mistake am I making?

```
Select count(*) from (
   select t1.CUST_ID, count(t1.qty)
   from TRANSACTIONS t1
   where t1.qty>0
   group by t1.CUST_ID
   having count(t1.qty)>10)
```

Comment: In SQL Server every derived table needs an alias

Comment: ...which also is according to the ISO/ANSI SQL standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide the aliases for your subquery and aggregated column:

```
Select count(*) from (
           select t1.CUST_ID, count(t1.qty) AS CNT
           from TRANSACTIONS t1
           where t1.qty>0
           group by t1.CUST_ID
           having count(t1.qty)>10
        ) AS T
```

Test it [here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/7cf8f46bc78693be0b518601efedb651/)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (to what Slava said), get rid of aggregate function in `select` clause altogether as you aren't really interested what it returns. You *would* need it if main `select` fetched that value as well, but - it doesn't.

```
select count(*)
from (select t1.cust_id
      from transactions t1
      where t1.qty > 0
      group by t1.cust_id
      having count(t1.qty) > 10
     ) as x
```